# Jquery load() form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony

I have a problem with my code. 
I am using `Jquery` load() to call a `form` in a `div` of my page. At the end of my page, I have `Jquery` code like date-picker and other.
The problem is that all the jquery code at the end of my page does not apply to the form called

```js
$(document).on('click', '.addtask', function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('class');

  $("." + id).load(Routing.generate('task_new', {
    id: id
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you add `jquery.min.js`?

Comment: call jquery.min.js before your jquery code

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is the problem that the datepicker is not being applied to dynamically-added elements? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247902/dynamic-jquery-ui-datepicker-elements

Answer (score 0):

Call jquery.min.js before your jquery code.
Like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


$(document).on('click', '.addtask', function() {
   var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('class');

   $("." + id).load(Routing.generate('task_new', {
     id: id
   }));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is not with the jquery call. In my code, it's in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget that for dynamically created elements this syntax will not work:

```
$('form').submit(function(){ alert('hi'); });
```

You should use this syntax:

```
$(window).on('submit', 'form', function() { alert('hi'); });
```